# What variable do i use when i'm declaring a variable such as A+

Tags: java

Im making a program that calculates one's gpa.  My variables include the grade A+ etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: a String variable? or maybe an enum?

Comment: Do you mean "what *datatype* do I use?" If that's the case I'd look at `enums`.

Comment: You should provide more details I think.

Comment: Java's an object-oriented language.  Your first thought should be a Grade class of some kind.  Encapsulate interpreting Strings like "A+"  and calculating GPA on the 0-4.0 scale.  Don't make clients deal with that complexity - hide it inside an object.

Answer (score 2):

I would create your own enum class.

```
enum Grade {
    A(4.0, "A"), B_PLUS(3.5, "B+"), B(3.0, "B"),  // etc.
      F(0, "F");

    private float gradePoints;
    private String asString;

    private Grade(float gradePoints, String asString) {
        this.gradePoints = gradePoints;
        this.asString = asString;
    }

    public float getGradePoints() {
        return gradePoints;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return asString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a good candidate for [Value Object](http://lostechies.com/joeocampo/2007/04/23/a-discussion-on-domain-driven-design-value-objects/) from Domain-Driven Design.

```
public class GpaGrade {
    private Int32 _inPercent;

    public GpaGrade(Int32 inPercent) {
        // TODO: check that inPercent is between 1 and 100
        _inPercent = inPercent;
    }

    public Int32 AsPercents() {
        return _inPercent;
    }

    public Double In40Scale() {
        // TODO: convert to 4.0 scale
    }

    public String AsLetterCode() {
        // TODO: convert to letter code
    }

    // TODO: override Equals and GetHashCode
}
```

Comment: k thanks im going to see what i can do with that